# For Loop - Box plots

Tags: r

In R, how do I create boxplots of specific columns with a for loop?

So far I have

```
for(colnames in c("Delivery, Free_wifi, Service, Alcohol")) {
    boxplot(df$Price ~ colnames) }
```

Comment: Can you provide a minimum working example? It's not clear what `df` is here.

Comment: your `c("Delivery, Free_wifi, Service, Alcohol")` is just one big string, it needs to be `c("Delivery", "Free_wifi", "Service", "Alcohol")`

Comment: Greetings! It would be helpful to provide a minimal reproducible dataset for us to work with. One way is by using `dput`. You can see how to use this command in the following video: https://youtu.be/3EID3P1oisg

Answer (score 0):

Using eval and as.name()

```r
df=data.frame(Price=c(rnorm(4,1,1),rnorm(5,2,1.5)),Delivery=c(rep('A',4),rep('B',5)),`Another Column`=c(rep('aa',3),rep('bb',3),rep('cc',3)),check.names = FALSE)
for(colnames in c("Delivery","Another Column")) {
  boxplot(Price ~ eval(as.name(colnames)),data=df) #eval
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much, this worked! Why do the boxplots only display in Source as opposed to Plots?

Comment: Not sure what do you mean by 'display in Source', could you give some examples?